# when working with php sessions form input data not getting save

Tags: php

Hey i have having a problem i just found working with session i am using at the moment firefox 23 but i have check that on some other browsers as well.
I have created a simple code where i have created a form and just opened a session and i have noticed that once i have submit the form and then click on "Go Back" to return to the page the info i have inserted is not saved on the browser.

Normally when you submit a form once you go back the data you have entered is saved and you can just edit the inputs and resent it but when i have used session_start() on the page that function stopped working.

Well i am guessing maybe the browser save the form data in sessions as well and once i use it in php it's somehow effect the normally way the browser work.

I hope someone know how i can fix that i know you are able to save sessions with html5 and javascript now but i would rather do that with php.

Attached below is the code i have been using:

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['name']= "name";
?>


<form method="post" action="index.php">

    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sessions have nothing to do with how the browser keeps previously filled out form fields.

Comment: Am pretty sure you meant to use `$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];`, right? Because what you have now, will have `name` as the session name, instead of the probable intended use of the form's (name) input. However, if you're using the entire code inside one page, you will need to use `isset`. Otherwise, you will get an undefined index error.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. for your question about the $_SESSION['name'] part the answer is no the session i have put there is just sample you can ignore i do not need the session to work with the form in this case that is not the problem. My problem is that in the moment i have use the code session_start(); inside the page once i have submitted form and press on go back the input field were empty but when i don't have the link session_start(); and i submit a form and go but the info i had inside the input filled are still there

Answer (score 0):

The browser refilling the form is simply that, the browser. This is not something you should rely upon for form re-population.

Your PHP code does not attempt to refill the form by printing anything within the input value="" attributes.

Generally when a form is submitted a programmer will validate the submitted values, store them in some fashion (the session is fine) and if they need them to reappear on the form they will print those values back out like I described.

Comment: Thanks for this advice at the moment if i won't find other option to fix that i will use your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put the CORRECT fields back into the form values and blank out the incorrect ones.  You don't have to use sessions:

```
<?php // formx.php
// accept POST variables
$fld1 = isset($_POST['fld1']) ? $_POST['fld1'] : "";
$fld2 = isset($_POST['fld2']) ? $_POST['fld2'] : "";
// edit variables
$errmsg = "";
if (!$fld1 == "") { if($fld1 <> "1") { $errmsg .= "fld1 is not 1<br />\n"; $fld1 = ""; } }
if (!$fld2 == "") { if($fld2 <> "2") { $errmsg .= "fld2 is not 2<br />\n"; $fld2 = ""; } }
if ($errmsg == "") { $errmsg = "Values accepted"; }
// output form
$body = <<<EOD
<html>
<body>
<div>%s</div><!-- errmsg -->
<form name="formnm" action="formx.php" method="post">
Enter "1" <input type="text" name="fld1" value="%s" /><br />
Enter "2" <input type="text" name="fld2" value="%s" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
printf($body, $errmsg, $fld1, $fld2);
?>
```

Comment: **dcromley** thanks for your replay as well the session i am using is for user login form that connect to my php system the form sample above was just a sample sorry if i didn't clearly convey my idea.

But checking again i see that most browser don't have that bug but it's mostly in firefox 23 which i am using.

Comment: @user3718754 - Maybe I need sessions to tell me when it's the first time in.  I need to look at my thing.